# How to switch between workspaces in ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, gnome, workspaces

I sent a window to another workspace in Ubuntu 10.04 but I am not able to go to that workspace. How do I do that ? Please let me know.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The default keyboard shortcut to switch between workspaces: <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>[arrow key]</kbd>

Comment: Thanks , that worked. Also my workspace switcher applet is gone from bottom right corner. How do I bring it back ?

Comment: @abc Right click on the panel, Select `Add to Panel` then choose `Workspace Switcher` from the list.